# Difference in Jquery response to selectors $('#tag_field_2') and $('input[style]')[0]

Tags: javascript, jquery

Both select the right element. But in the case of

```
$('#tag_field_2')
```

the response is in square brackets, in the case of

```
$('input[style]')[0]
```

it isn't. To be able to use a function on the response I need the square brackets. But why? I want to use the 2nd selector but

```
$('input[style]')[0].show();
```

it gives me

```
 Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

Comment: Please provide HTML and jsFiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$('input[style]')[0]` return dom object of first element in matched elements and you can not use jquery methods and property on DOM object.you need to use `:first` or `:eq(0)` to target the first element:

```
$('input[style]:first').show();
```

or

```
$('input[style]:eq(0)').show();
```

Answer (score 3):

When you use the indexer on the jQuery object, it returns the DOM element object, not another jQuery object.

Try this selector:

```
$('input[style]:eq(0)').show();
```

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick. Didn't know how to decide which answer to mark as correct. But the one I finally chose explains a bit more detailed.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
$('input[style]:lt(1)').show();
```

Or

```
$('input[style]:eq(0)').show();
```

Basically both are same.It grabs 0th element to show .It can be achieved using `lt(1)` or `eq(0)` as both select 0th element only.

Comment: Please edit your answer, and explain why this is a good solution.

Comment: @Ben , see basically `$('input[style]:lt(1)').show(); ` And using `:eq(0)').` are both same , getting ?